# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: freezes app, not a crash

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios4, uikit, modalviewcontroller

**Edit-**
I had accidentally synthesized parentViewController

Edit/

This was working, and now it isn't, I don't think that I have done anything in code that would affect this behavior.
Here is what I am doing:
I have a view and associated view controller, called `NewAssetViewController`. NewAssetViewController's view has a mixture of `UITextField`s `and UITextView`s:
[image]
when I click on the `UITextView` I receive the delegate method `textViewShouldBeginEditing:`
in this method I present my customController view called `MultiPicker`:

```
[self presentModalViewController:multiPicker animated:YES];
```

if the user selects a button on this interface it either cancels, or returns selecting a value, I will only use the cancel case because it behaves the same way, and doesn't have any extra code.

multipicker's cancel method:

```
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
//close returning nothing...
    [delegate multiPickerDidCancel:self];
}
```

which calls `NewAssetController`'s `multiPickerDidCancel:` method:

```
-(void)multiPickerDidCancel:(MultiPicker *)aMultiPicker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [aMultiPicker reset];

}
```

at this point now it freezes, doesn't crash, if I pause the debugger, this is what the trace looks like:
[image]

 with the frame above representing some assembly:

```
0x00ec121e  <+0317>  mov    %eax,%edi
0x00ec1220  <+0319>  jmp    0xec11bb <-[UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerWithTransition:]+218>
0x00ec1222  <+0321>  mov    0x4e446b(%ebx),%eax
0x00ec1228  <+0327>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x00ec122c  <+0331>  mov    %edi,(%esp)
0x00ec122f  <+0334>  call   0x128e98a <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x00ec1234  <+0339>  mov    %eax,-0x1c(%ebp)
0x00ec1237  <+0342>  mov    0x4e1bcb(%ebx),%edx
0x00ec123d  <+0348>  mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
0x00ec1241  <+0352>  mov    %esi,(%esp)
0x00ec1244  <+0355>  call   0x128e98a <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x00ec1249  <+0360>  cmpl   $0x3,-0x20(%ebp)
0x00ec124d  <+0364>  jne    0xec1277 <-[UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerWithTransition:]+406>
0x00ec124f  <+0366>  mov    0x4e295f(%ebx),%eax
0x00ec1255  <+0372>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x00ec1259  <+0376>  mov    %edi,(%esp)
```

Comment: I just created a test project and did the same, and everything worked, so I suspect maybe it has to do with that picker you have on the modal view controller. Try to create a really basic Modal view controller (let's say, only a button) and see what happens.

Comment: I think I had Accidentally synthesized parentViewController... damn text completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had accidentally synthesized `parentViewController`, not my day...